# Access Denied: "project name": User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in "project name"

Tags: google-bigquery, access-denied

So I have a problem creating new dataset in bigquery due to

> Access Denied: "project name": User does not have bigquery.jobs.create
> permission in "project name".

Could someone help me with what it means and how to fix it? because I'm kind of confused since this is my own personal project and so I'm the owner of this project which supposedly gives me all the access to this project.

Comment: There are 2 projects in BQ, which is confusing. 1- The project your data is stored. 2- Billing Project (chosen from dropdown on top). This error is about the second one. So are you sure you're using the billing project that you own?

Comment: I haven't set up billing to upgrade my BigQuery, is that the reason why I get this error? but I was able to create several datasets before without any issues.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be about it. Just be sure you have chosen the correct billing project from the top. If still not works, you can grant BigQuery Admin role to yourself, maybe.

Comment: @byrmn__ 
This seems to be a permission issue. Can you make sure that you are using the correct project and account? To find the project you are using:`gcloud config get-value project`. You can list your project by `gcloud projects list` and then set the project by `gcloud config set project {PROJECT-ID}`”.You can also find credentialed accounts by `gcloud auth list`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't how or why this is happening, but somehow it was fixed now after I tried to upload another CSV file.